# Django form - filter foreignkey in model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

Let's assume that we have 2 models:

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    number = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="#")
    product = models.ForeignKey(Application, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Application')

class Application(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_number=100)
    defaultCalendar = models.ForeignKey(Calendar)
class Calendar(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_number=100)
```

And form:

```
class EntryForm(ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = Entry
    fields = {'product ', 'number'}
```

1) In the documentation we can read that using `fields` we can change the ordering of the model, however in this example it doesn't work :(

2) Is there a way to filter product in my Form ? In the views with model I can do that this way

```
def somefunction(request, val1, val2):
    products = Application.objects.filter(defaultCalendar=request.user.get_profile().defaultCalendar)
```

`get_profile` is a function which returns profile of the user.

Anyway to do that in Form?
The filter argument must be connected with usere who executed the function.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) it doesn't work because "fields" should be a list:

```
fields = ['product ', 'number', ]
```

2)

You can use:

```
form.fields["product"].queryset = your_queryset
```